# Why don't my views update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am creating a test application. So far, it's working, but when I make some minor changes to my views, the page doesn't change.

My problem may be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87802/why-does-rails-cache-view-files-when-hosted-on-vm-and-codebase-on-samba-share), but I'm not sure what is meant by setting the date and time in the VM. My code is on a remotely hosted server, so I assume it would use the system time of that machine.

Is there a caching issue here? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restart your Rails app (or Apache if you are using Passenger) if you are in production mode!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have control over the server environment yourself (no shell access, etc.), you can set the following at the top of `config/environment.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'
```

Development doesn't cache much, so while it's slower it's much nicer to develop in.

You'll still need to restart your app after making changes to anything outside the `app/` folder though (configs, plugins, etc.).

Comment: I did this, but changes still don't show until I restart Mongrel. (I do have SSH access.)

Comment: Try getting your templates to echo `Rails.env`, to see if it's actually being picked up by Rails.

What version of Rails are you running? (Echo `Rails.version` in your template)